# Why configuring route prevent caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache

I simply define extra url route as below for Home/Index action method.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Playlists",
            url: "Home/Playlists",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

And here is my Index action with OutputCache Attribute

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, NoStore = true, VaryByCustom = "canVisit")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

OutputCache attribute works well when user nagivates /Home/Index url but it doesn't work at all when user navigates /Home/Playlists url. Why this routing prevent output cache ?

Comment: If you hit /Playlists after the first request, is it then cached?

Comment: @maf748 No it is not cached even after first request.

Answer (score 0):

You're caching the results of that specific Action based on URL...so in your case, the cache is storing two copies, one keyed by /Index and one keyed by /Playlists.

Comment: But it is not even cached for /Playlists. Anytime /Playlists requested, it invoked again.